# Ocultar imagen dentro de un div ni bien carga la página

Tags: jquery, html5

Estoy queriendo que se oculte, **ni bien carga la página**, una imagen de tipo .gif que está dentro de un **div**. Pero no comprendo por qué se muestra dicha imagen, si yo estoy ocultando el **div** desde `JQuery` de la siguiente forma (`$("#carga").hide();`)

En `HTML` lo tengo así dentro del body:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
...
    <div id='carga'><img src="Imagenes/Carga2.gif" alt="Cargando artículo..."></div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

... y luego desde `JQuery` lo oculto ni bien carga la página, pero esto no sucede. **Siempre se muestra cuando se carga la página**:

```
<script>
$().ready(function()
{
    $("#carga").hide();
    ...
    ...
});
</script>
```

Además lo estoy ocultado en el load, no entiendo que pasa y porque me muestra dicha imagen. ¿Será que el `<div id='carga'>` no puede ocultar otro objeto dentro suyo, en este caso de tipo *img*?

**Nota**: La imagen se muestra cuando se carga la página, pero **desaparece a los pocos segundos**, luego de terminar de cargar demás cosas de JQuery (botones, jQuery Autocomplete...). Aclarar también que la línea `$("#carga").hide();` esta puesta al principio de todo en el `$().ready(function(){...`.

Comment: Tu codigo funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

He puesto tu código en un snipet y funciona muy bien.

Lo que también puedes haces es ocultarlo con `attr` desde `Jquery` así:

```js
$().ready(function() {
    $("#carga").attr("hidden", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Este div incial no esta oculto </div>
<br>
<div><img src="Imagenes/Carga2.gif" alt="Cargando artículo..."></div>
<br>
<div id='carga'><img src="Imagenes/Carga2.gif" alt="Cargando artículo..."></div>
<br>
<div>Este div final no esta oculto </div>
```

Si ves el código agregue varios `div` para que puedas ver cual esta y cual no oculto.

Comment: No, si tengo las referencias, sólo que aquí no las puse. Es muy raro lo que pasa. De todas formas por el momento lo solucione agregando  `display:none ` o sea  `<div id='carga' style='display:none'>`. No sé si es la mejor solución, pero **de esta manera no me carga la imagen**.

Comment: o puedes probar la propiedad `attr`, ya modifico la respuesta y realizas la prueba

Comment: Modifique la respuesta realiza la prueba a ver si te funciona con `attr` si no porfa edita tu pregunta y sube todo el código para poder encontrar el error.

Comment: No, no pasa nada. Me doy cuenta que desde JQuery **lo llega a ocultar luego de unos segundos** (después de cargar ciertas otras cosas como botones, jquery autocomplete...). Sólo desde HTML5 lo hace de inmediato, como ya dije, agregando `display:none`. Todo el código es muy largo, por eso no lo pongo y solo puse una parte. Se perderían más si lo pusiera (es que tengo mucho código de PHP y de JavaScript).

Comment: Debes de poner el codigo que oculta , de primero en el document.ready ya que si lo pones al final o en la mitad primero va hacer lo que tienes antes y por eso se muestra hasta que llega al fragmento donde lo oculta, por eso en el snipet funciona bien por que solo esta ese codigo

Comment: Si, está a principio de todo. Es como tal cuál lo puse aquí al comienzo y luego los puntos (`...`) para indicar que viene todo lo demás de JQuery.

Comment: Entonces , debes subir tu codigo completo para poder identificar el error